# Conversion errors from Swift 3.0 to Swift 4.2 "Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[AVMetadataObject.ObjectType]?'"

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, swift4.2, xcode10.3

I am new to Swift/iOS development and am working on Converting a Swift 3.0 project to Swift 4.2 in order to support newer devices.

In the process I am getting the following error :

> Cannot assign value of type '[String]' to type '[AVMetadataObject.ObjectType]?'

Below are the lines of code throwing the error:

```
let metadataOutput = AVCaptureMetadataOutput()

metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.upce),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code39Mod43),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean13),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.ean8),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code93),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.code128),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.pdf417),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.aztec),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.interleaved2of5),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.itf14),
                                      convertFromAVMetadataObjectObjectType(AVMetadataObject.ObjectType.dataMatrix)]// Support for AVMetadataObjectTypeQRCode / qr code is removed from the list.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migrator helps at its best but sometimes the help is misleading.

You can populate the array just with the static members

```
metadataOutput.metadataObjectTypes = [.upce, .code39, .code39Mod43, .ean13, .ean8, .code93, .code128, .pdf417, .aztec, .interleaved2of5, .itf14, .dataMatrix]
```